# Фибоначчи за O(1)

Tags: алгоритм, сложность, числа-фибоначчи

Можно ли вычислить n-ое число последовательности Фибоначчи за константное время O(1)?

По идее, формула Бине позволяет найти требуемое число за константное количество операций. Однако как быть с возведением в степень? Оно ведь не может происходить за константное время, насколько я знаю. В лучшем случае за логарифм...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

С уверенностью можно сказать, что за O(1) вычислить n-ое число Фибоначчи нельзя, потому что, как миниммум, длина ответа неограничено растет вместе с n.

Возведение в степень чисел с плавающей точкой происходит за константное время, но дает приближенный результат. Поэтому вычисление по формуле Бине будет давать вам не числа Фибоначчи, а грубые приближения.